# Further optimization of file transfer over FIFO on linux?

Tags: c, linux

For learning purposes I'm writing a very simple mqueue based file transfer server. Below is a thread function that takes care of an incoming request:

```
static void * handle_client_request(const char *request_string) {
    char request_pathname[_part_delim_alloc_size],
         request_fifo_name[_part_delim_alloc_size];

    bool parse_ret = parse_mqueue_request_string(request_string, (char *[]) {request_pathname, request_fifo_name});
    if(!parse_ret) {
        fprintf(stderr, PROGNAME ": error parsing mqueue request string: %s\n", request_string);
        free(request_string);
        return NULL;
    }

    fprintf(stdout, PROGNAME ": received new request: (%s, %s) -- handling\n", request_pathname, request_fifo_name);

    // open requested file for reading
    int file_fd = open(request_pathname, O_RDONLY);
    if(file_fd == -1) {
        perror(PROGNAME ": error opening requsted file");
        free(request_string);
        return NULL;
    }

    // construct full FIFO path
    char full_fifo_path[strlen(FIFO_STORAGE_PATH) + strlen(request_fifo_name) + 1];
    strcpy(full_fifo_path, FIFO_STORAGE_PATH);
    strncat(full_fifo_path, request_fifo_name, 11);

    // open FIFO for writing only -- this may block until client also opens the FIFO
    int fifo_fd = open(full_fifo_path, O_WRONLY);
    if(fifo_fd == -1) {
        perror(PROGNAME ": failed opening FIFO for writing");
        close(file_fd);
        free(request_string);
        return NULL;
    }

    void *buf = malloc(DEFAULT_BUFSIZE); // 128 KiB, 2^17 bytes
    if(!buf) {
        perror(PROGNAME ": failed allocating buffer");
        close(file_fd);
        close(fifo_fd);
        free(request_string);
        return NULL;
    }

    size_t bread;
    while((bread = read(file_fd, buf, DEFAULT_BUFSIZE)) > 0) {
        // read call complete, "bread" bytes are now in "buf"
        ssize_t bwritten = write(fifo_fd, buf, bread);

        if(bwritten == -1) {
            // failed writing the batch of bytes received
            fprintf(stderr, PROGNAME ": failed writing to FIFO - request aborted (%s): %s\n", full_fifo_path, strerror(errno));
            free(buf);
            free(request_string);
            close(file_fd);
            close(fifo_fd);
            return NULL;
        }

        /* fprintf(stdout, PROGNAME ": read %lu bytes of data and wrote %ld bytes of data\n", bread, bwritten); */
    }

    fprintf(stdout, PROGNAME ": done processing request (%s, %s) last bread: %lu\n", request_pathname, request_fifo_name, bread);

    close(file_fd);
    close(fifo_fd);
    free(buf);

    return NULL;
}
```

Its purpose is to transfer a local file (that the client requests) over a FIFO that the client connects to.

The size of the buffer for `read(2)` and `write(2)` I've decided on is 128KiB. Increasing it doesn't seem to have an positive effect on performance.

I am wondering - are there any trivial (or not so trivial) optimizations I could apply to this function to gain an ever so slight increase in performance?

Answer (score 1):

### Const

I consider

```
const char *request_string
```

and

```
free(request_string);
```

to be in conflict. If the contract for this function is that it is responsible for freeing the string it was given, it should not be `const`. Conversely, if you really think it should be `const`, shift responsibility of freeing it onto the caller.

### Stack allocation

In C terms, support for dynamic stack allocation of the kind seen in

```
char full_fifo_path[strlen(FIFO_STORAGE_PATH) + strlen(request_fifo_name) + 1];
```

is relatively new. If I were you I would be concerned that a hostile caller could pass a huge string in `request_string`, which parses into a huge `request_fifo_name` and blows the stack. As long as you take care to free the memory yourself through the various `return` paths in this function, I would consider `malloc` safer.

Comment: In this particular case the maximum allowed length of `request_string` is set as a runtime parameter, although it cannot exceed linux's maximum `mqueue` message length (`8192` bytes), which is still far less than the stack size. Still a good idea to switch to malloc though, will definitely do that! Thank you!